# How to get the height of the GNOME top (menu)bar?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Originally the idea was simple: save tkinter window(s) configuration for some MusicApp that when the app was launched again all the windows were positioned as at the time of saving (width, heigh too).

It turned out (after a while) that to do that I need to know the GNOME3 top(menu)bar height.

Toplevel.geometry() function is used for saving geometry strings in the musicapp.ini file. When the app is launched again, adjust_geometry() function is applied to every geometry sting from .ini file.

```
def adjust_geometry(g):
    GNOMEMENUBARHEIGHT = 27

    def fix_y(requested_y):
        return requested_y + GNOMEMENUBARHEIGHT

    w, h, x, y = MusicApp.parse_geometry(g)
    return f'{w}x{h}+{x}+{fix_y(y)}'
```

screenruler was used to compare "before/after" geometries.

Below is a byproduct of my "research".

```
import re
from operator import sub
import tkinter as tk
# g0 - initially requested geometry. After suppressing the tkinter
# window titlebar, 0 (y) becomes the GNOME titlebar height
g0 = '900x300+100+0'


def parse_geometry(g):
    m = re.match(r'(\d+)x(\d+)\+(\d+)\+(\d+)', g)
    return map(int, m.groups())


def print_geometry():
    '''Prints 0x37+0+27

    where 37 is the tkitner window titlebar height, 27 is the GNOME
    menubar height

    '''

    t.update_idletasks()
    g1 = t.geometry()
    print('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(*map(sub, parse_geometry(g1),
                                    parse_geometry(g0))))


def hide_titlebar():
    t.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')  # alas, irreversible!


def print_titlebar_size(step=0):
    if step == 0:
        hide_titlebar()
        t.after(500, lambda: print_titlebar_size(1))
    elif step == 1:
        print_geometry()
        t.after(500, lambda: print_titlebar_size(2))
    else:
        t.quit()


r = tk.Tk()
t = tk.Toplevel(r)
t.title('MusicApp')
t.geometry(g0)
tk.Button(t, text='Print titlebar size', command=print_titlebar_size).pack()
r.withdraw()
t.after(500, print_titlebar_size)
r.mainloop()
```

it prints 0x37+0+27 where 37 (pixels) is the height of a tkinter window titlebar, and 27 is the height of the GNOME menubar.

Since wm_attributes('-type', 'splash') is irreversible (or I do not know how get the title bars back) printtitlebarsize.py has to be run as a standalone process (it can't be a function in the MusicApp app)

Using:

GNOME 3.38.5
Python 3.9.2
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)